# I can't connect into the OPC Server

Tags: c#, opc-ua, industrial

for me is the first time to work with OPC UA. I red a lot of pace, I'd download the library OPCDAAuto.dll, I registrered it, I copied some codo to test it, but I go against mistakes. And I tried other way, but I get the same result.

My code, with OPDAAuto.dll is that:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    OPCServer ObjOPCServer;
    OPCGroups ObjOPCGroups;
    OPCGroup ObjOPCGroup;
    string OPCServerName;

    public Form1()
    {
        try
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            OPCServerName = "opc.tcp://co15:62841/TVM_CNC_NY16006/uaPLUS";
            ObjOPCServer = new OPCServer(); //error appears at this point (*)
            ObjOPCServer.Connect(OPCServerName, "");
            ObjOPCGroups = ObjOPCServer.OPCGroups;
            ObjOPCGroup = ObjOPCGroups.Add("OPCGroup1");
            ObjOPCGroup.DataChange += new DIOPCGroupEvent_DataChangeEventHandler(ObjOPCGroup_DataChange);
            ObjOPCGroup.OPCItems.AddItem("{tag name or address (like {plc name on server}!%mw0)}", 1);
            ObjOPCGroup.UpdateRate = 10;
            ObjOPCGroup.IsActive = true;
            ObjOPCGroup.IsSubscribed = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

The error appears at this point: ObjOPCServer = new OPCServer(); (*):

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800d0154): Recovery of the COM class factory for the component with CLSID {serial-number} failed due to the following error: 80040154 {REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG}

Someone can help me? Please

Comment: If you need to connect to the server why are you creating a server? Shouldn't you use a client object?

Comment: Either OPC or OPC-UA, those are completely different frameworks. Please correct your post and remove also one of the incorrect tags.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the URL you put into OPCServerName, and what you wrote in your introduction, you are trying to connect to OPC UA server.

But the library your are using is for OPC "Classic" Data Access. It cannot be used to connect to OPC UA servers.

You need a different library. There are some free libraries (for example, UA-.NETStandard repository form OPC Foundation, https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard ) or some commercial ones (for example QuickOPC, https://www.opclabs.com/products/quickopc/languages-and-tools/csharp ). Disclaimer: I am QuickOPC author.

Comment: When I try to connect into the endpoint with github library, give me this message: "The security certificate was not issued by a trusted certificate authority. Security certificate problems may indicate an attempt to intercept any data you send to server or to allow an untrusted client to connect to your server. Accept anyway?"

Comment: That message I guess will be from the server ? . I believe that the vast majority of OPC UA clients do not use certificates issued by a trusted authority. The reason is simple, they cost money. In order to connect, the server should accept that certificate, although if you are connecting without security mode the certificate is not really necessary.

Comment: You are on the right way - but you should enter a new StackOverflow question as you now have a different problem.